# Python OpenCV Error: cv2.error :-1: error: in function 'imshow'

Tags: python

I started to learn OpenCV today and faced a small problem:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
```

You can use this issue just to warm up before going to solve more complicated questions:)

Thank you!

**The code:**

```py
import cv2 as cv 

img = R'Photos and videos\Photos and videos\Dogs photo.jpg'

cv.imread = img

cv.imshow("Dog", img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\read.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv.imshow("Dog", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv.imread()` is a function which takes in a "path" as an argument, so you need to pass the path to your image to it and it will then return the CV2 Image object, which you can pass that `imshow()` to display.

```
import cv2 as cv 

path = R'Photos and videos\Photos and videos\Dogs photo.jpg'

img = cv.imread(path)

cv.imshow("Dog", img)

cv.waitKey(0)
```